# Bad request error when sending http request to graph api for change notification

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am sending http request to graph api to subscribe for change notififications.
My code:

```
public class GraphManager : RestClient, IGraphManager
{
    #region Private members

    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private static Dictionary<string, Subscription> Subscriptions = new Dictionary<string, Subscription>();
    private static Timer? subscriptionTimer = null;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public GraphManager(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(GetBaseUri(), GetAuthenticator(configuration, httpContextAccessor))
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private methods

    private static Uri GetBaseUri()
    {
        return new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com");
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, string> GetRequestHeaders()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "ConsistencyLevel", "eventual" }
            };
    }

    private static IAuthenticator GetAuthenticator(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        HttpRequest request = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;

        return new ConfidentialClientAuthenticator(configuration["Apps:Api:ClientId"],
            configuration["Apps:Api:ClientSecret"], configuration["Auth:Authority"],
            $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}", new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public methods

    public async Task<string> GetSubscription()
    {
        var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
        sub.ChangeType = "updated";
        sub.NotificationUrl = "https://ngrok.url/api/notifications";
        sub.Resource = "/users";
        sub.ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15);
        sub.ClientState = "SecretClientState";

        string jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(sub);

        string url = "v1.0/subscriptions";
        var response = await ProcessRequestAsync(HttpMethod.Post, url, jsonString);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var subscriptionResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return subscriptionResponse;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to create subscription: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
        }


    }
    #endregion
}

public class RestClient : IDisposable
{
    #region Private members

    private readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    private readonly Uri _baseUri;
    private readonly IAuthenticator _authenticator;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public RestClient(Uri baseUri, IAuthenticator authenticator, int timeout = 0)
    {
        _baseUri = baseUri;
        _authenticator = authenticator;

        if (timeout > 0)
        {
            _client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
        }
    }

    public RestClient(IAuthenticator authenticator)
        : this(null, authenticator)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable implementation

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private methods

    private Uri GetRequestUri(string requestUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestUrl))
        {
            if (_baseUri == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid (empty) URL");

            return _baseUri;
        }
        else if (requestUrl.StartsWith("http://") || requestUrl.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            return new Uri(requestUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            if (_baseUri == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid (relative) URL");

            return _baseUri.Append(requestUrl);
        }
    }


    #endregion

    #region Protected methods

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _client?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    protected string GetErrorFromResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        return $"{response.StatusCode} (Details: '{response.Content.AsString()}')";
    }

    protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessRequestAsync(HttpMethod httpMethod, string url,
                HttpContent content = null, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
    {
        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = httpMethod,
            RequestUri = GetRequestUri(url),
            Content = content
        })
        {
            UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(GetRequestUri(url));

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> parameter in parameters)
                {
                    query[parameter.Key] = parameter.Value;
                }

                uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
            }

            request.RequestUri = uriBuilder.Uri;

            if (_authenticator != null)
            {
                IDictionary<string, string> authenticationHeaders = _authenticator.GetAuthenticationHeaders(request);

                if (authenticationHeaders != null)
                {
                    foreach (var header in authenticationHeaders)
                    {
                        request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var header in headers)
                {
                    request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }
            }

            return await _client.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }

    protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessRequestAsync(HttpMethod httpMethod, string url, string contentJson, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
    {
        HttpContent httpContent = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentJson))
            httpContent = new StringContent(contentJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        return await ProcessRequestAsync(httpMethod, url, httpContent, headers);
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class UriExtensions
{
    public static Uri Append(this Uri uri, params string[] paths)
    {
        return new Uri(paths.Aggregate(uri.AbsoluteUri, (current, path) => $"{current.TrimEnd('/')}/{path.TrimStart('/')}"));
    }
}
```

But i dont get error when i use it like

```
      var graphServiceClient = GetGraphClient();

      var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
      sub.ChangeType = "updated";
      sub.NotificationUrl = "https://76d2-2405-201-5c1d-405f-6845-eec-7804-46a1.ngrok-free.app/api/notifications";
      sub.Resource = "/users";
      sub.ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15);
      sub.ClientState = "SecretClientState";

      var newSubscription = await graphServiceClient
        .Subscriptions
        .Request()
        .AddAsync(sub);

      Subscriptions[newSubscription.Id] = newSubscription;
```

My notification url is same in both the request objects.

Why i am not able to send http request?

Sending http request gives bad request error. System.Exception: BadRequest (Details: '{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Could not process subscription creation payload. Are all property names spelled and camelCased properly?Also are the dateTimeOffest properties in a valid internet Date and Time format?"

Answer (score 0):

In the following query

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-type: application/json

{
   "changeType": "created",
   "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/NotifClient",
   "resource": "/users",
   "expirationDateTime":"2018-11-20T18:23:45.9778678Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue",
   "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```

I received error when in payload something went wrong.

[image]

In the above case expiration date given was invalid.
And so payload error occurred.
Make sure to give all the parameters correctly.

Check [Receive change notifications through webhooks - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery-webhooks?tabs=http#notificationurl-validation)

notificationUrl' must  respond to the request for validation. Make sure the validation token from microsoft graph is decode or retured as  **plain/text** .

Also check [Events subscription via webhooks using MS graph | StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340875/events-subscription-via-webhooks-using-ms-graph-android-sdk)

[image]